# Meaning of "prominent voice"

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns

> A prominent voice among clean-energy advocates, Mr. Quinn is frequently asked to speak at industry events as well as on college campuses, both domestically and abroad.

What does "voice" mean in this sentence? voice = Mr. Quinn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means Mr. Quinn is a well respected person often speaks up for clean-energy advocates. Bascially meaning he sort of represents the group of clean-energy advocates and is the main "voice" behind them. So you could say he "speaks" for them.